# Rename tag [opa]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

There's a tag called [opa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opa) on Stack Overflow that relates to

> an open source programming language for both backend and frontend web development.

The tag definition points to http://opalang.org/

We should rename the tag from `opa` to `opa-lang` to avoid confusion with Open Policy Agent ([open-policy-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-policy-agent)) as it is an entirely different technology.

Comment: Skimmed [opa] questions and it looks like _most_ of them are actually about Open Policy Agent, not the opa language. Simply renaming the tag would not be enough – some kind of cleanup is needed too.

Comment: true - I can skim through those and remove the opa tag and/or make sure the Open Policy Agent tag is assigned